# Fatal Error: Function name

Tags: php

Im getting an Error:

`FATAL ERROR: Function name Must be a string in C:\xampp\localhost\student\viewgrades.php on line 78`.

I wanted to make an if Statement if the grade is more than 75 then it should `echo 'passed'`, but if the calculated grade is below 75 i should `'echo failed'`.

Sorry for the code structure my knowledge for PHP is still limited

```
<?php
$resultp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prelcent");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($resultp);

$prelcent=$row['percentage'];

$resultpp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM midcent");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($resultpp);

$midcent=$row['percentage'];

$resultppp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM precent");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($resultppp);

$precent=$row['percentage'];

$resultpppp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fincent");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($resultpppp);

$fincent=$row['percentage'];

$remark = (($pre*$prelcent)+($mid*$midcent)+($prf*$precent)+($fin*$fincent));
    if ($remark() >75)   <<<<<Line 78 {
        $rem1 = "echo 'passed!';";
    } else {
        if ($remark()<75) {
            $rem1 = "echo 'failed';";
        }
    }
    echo "<td>". $rem1 ."</td>"
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try with

```
if ($remark >75)
```

Because `$remark` is **not** a `function`.Its a **variable** that to the result of

```
($pre*$prelcent)+($mid*$midcent)+($prf*$precent)+($fin*$fincent)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$remark`  is **variable**, not a `function`, So it should be , also `$rem1 = "passed!";` instead of `$rem1 = "echo 'passed!';";`

```
if ($remark > 75){
     $rem1 = "passed!";
}
```

instead of

```
if ($remark() > 75){
   $rem1 = "echo 'passed!';";
}
```

Your code should be like,

```
 $remark = (($pre*$prelcent)+($mid*$midcent)+($prf*$precent)+($fin*$fincent));
 if ($remark > 75) {
    $rem1 = "passed!";
 } else {
    if ($remark < 75) {
        $rem1 = "failed";
    }
 }
 echo "<td>". $rem1 ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$rem1 = "echo 'passed!';"; makes it look like a function. In order for it to look like a variable it should be $rem1 = "passed!";